# Loading dynamic content with JQuery and ASP

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dynamic, get, load

So I have the following code:

```
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-link]', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        url = $this.data('link');
        $("#imagePreview").load("imageProcess.aspx?" + url);
    });
```

This is supposed to send GET data into imageProcess.aspx, and then append the output to the div id "imagePreview".  url stores data from here:

```
<a class='modelsBlue' href = '#' data-link='model="+$(this).find('model').text()+"&type="+category+"'>" + $(this).find("model").text() + "</a>
```

The problem I'm running into is that nothing is being displayed when I run this code.  For right now my .aspx file holds just this:

```
<%
   Response.Write(Request.QueryString("model"))
   Response.Write(Request.QueryString("type"))
%>
```

I'm very new to asp.net coming from a php background, so I'm certain that the problem lies in the asp file, but I've been looking online for a solution and I haven't been able to find anything.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image is a stream over HTTP, or might be embedded in an HTML document using base64 encoding. What are you returning back from `imageProcess.aspx` file? Do you set proper `Content-Type` headers in HTTP response (things like `image/png` or `image/jpg`)?

Update: I recommend that you first get sure that where the problem is. Install [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and run your code. See the HTTP traffic through Fiddler. This way, you can see what has been returned back by server (you can see HTTP response body). If nothing is sent back, then the problem is in server. If something is sent back, but not shown, then of course you have to check the client.

Comment: well for right now I just want the original page to display raw text returned from the .asp file so that I know it's working.  What I have up there is literally all that is in the asp file, and the content being sent over is just two strings through GET parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a program that will show you exactly what is being sent and received on your ajax calls. Personally I use http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/.

If you don't feel like using a new program I'd add some extra code into the asp file to verify you are getting the expected query string. ie changing them to be

`Response.Write("model:" & Request.QueryString("model"))`

Then add a callback function to $("#imagePreview").load to see exactly what you get as a response.